# Finding minimum element in array using recursion

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, c++14

so I'm having trouble trying to understand how recursion of this code works.

```
int minimum(int array[], int size) {
    if (size == 1) {
        return array[0];
    }
    else {
        return (array[size] < int min = minimum(array, size - 1))? array[size] : min;
    }
}

int array[4] = {5, 99, 205, 1};
int smallest = minimum(array, 3); // 3 = index of the last element
```

Here is the explanation I saw: this function searches the lowest value in an int array by using recursion. At first it checks how many elements are in the array by checking if the size equals to 1 and then returns the first value as result. If the table is bigger than 1 (and technically also when lower) it compares the last value in the array with the recursive call with the rest of the array.

The recursion stops at the 0-index and then compares that value with the index 1. Then it compares the lowest value of index 0 and 1 with the value from index 3 and so on until it reaches last value.

But I still can't imagine how the recursion run in my head, especially `min = minimum(array, size - 1)` .
Can someone be so kind to explain it to my slow brain how this code run in stack?
Thank you so much.

Comment: That code is wrong – `if (size == 1)` should be `if (size == 0)`.

Comment: @Chronial - No, size==1 is right

Comment: `array[size] < int min` seams to be wrong syntax.

Comment: @Chronial  in this case ```size``` is index of last element though, so it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the code (by accessing `array[size-1]` instead of `array[size]` and simplified it a bit (by using `std::min`).

```
int minimum(int array[], int size) {
    if (size == 1) {
        return array[0];
    } else {
        return std::min(array[size - 1], minimum(array, size - 1))
    }
}

int array[4] = {5, 99, 205, 1};
int smallest = minimum(array, 4);
```

Now you might be able to see that `minimum(array, 4)` is equal to `std::min(array[3], minimum(array, 3))`, is equal to `std::min(array[3], std::min(array[2], minimum(array, 2)))` ... is equal to `std::min(array[3], std::min(array[2], std::min(array[1], array[0])))`.